# How to export CryptoKey?

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, aes

I try to export an generated Key in Web Cryptography API/SubtleCrypto.

When I'm execute crypto.subtle.exportKey I receive following error messages:
in Chrome:

> DOMException: key is not extractable (InvalidAccessError)

and in Firefox

> A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object (InvalidAccessError)

```
cryptoTestObject = crypto.subtle.generateKey(
            {
                name: "AES-CBC",
                length: 256, //can be  128, 192, or 256
            },
            false, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //can "encrypt", "decrypt", "wrapKey", or "unwrapKey"
        )
        .then(function (key) {
            //returns a key object
            saveKeyInLocalStorage(keyName, key);
            console.log('CryptoPromise' + key);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

function saveKeyInLocalStorage(keyName, aesKey) {
    var exportPromise = crypto.subtle.exportKey('raw', aesKey);
    exportPromise.then(function (aesKey_RAW) {
        localStorage.setItem(keyName + 'key', aesKey_RAW);
        console.log("saved.");
    });
}
```

How can i generate a key which is exportable in raw format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're generating the key with the extractable setting set to `false`. Set it to `true` instead:

```
crypto.subtle.generateKey(
    {
        name: "AES-CBC",
        length: 256
    },
    true, // <-- here
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
)
```